# How to visualize pores using material studio?

Tags: visualization-software

I am a newbie to material studio. I have a membrane, coordinates are in pdb format. I am trying to visualize the pores of this membrane. I tried Atoms and Volume surfaces, but the result was that the VdW surfaces were also shown. I also unchecked the VdW surfaces in analysis window, but it still shows. My probe radius is 1 angstrom. Is there anyway that I can just visualize the pores. I am attaching a picture of the settings and my output.
This is what I am looking for. Figure 1d in https://www.nature.com/articles/nmat4638

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1. It might be easier if you take a screenshot with your computer rather than a photograph with your camera!

Comment: Could you share the PDB of the membrane?

Comment: @Camps Shared the pdb

Comment: Is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6-uryDQQCaPAzIfLv3Es5JLclIJqo8B/view?usp=sharing) what you need?

Comment: @Camps Quite opposite of that. I think you have shown connolly  surface. My requirement is the lets take a probe of radius 1 ang, I want to show all the pores which are 1 ang and above. That means in the figure you sent, the black regions in the middle of the membrane should be highlighted whereas the molecules can be in CPK or lines representation without any surface surrounding it.

Comment: The black color is the backgroundś color, so, if you see it, it is because your seeing through a porous. I used a 1Angst to create the molecular surface. I did it with MAESTRO. Sorry if I can not help more.

Comment: I gave +1 on the answer, but in general I don't recommend people to "accept" their own answers: If it was someone else that wrote the answer, you would get +2 for accepting it, and the "accepted" answer moves to the top of the list of answers, but if you accept your own answer you don't get the +2 and the question does not move to the top of the list. The green checkmark also discourages others with possibly better answers, from writing more answers. So for these reasons I generally don't recommend self-accepting, but it's also perfectly okay to do in some situations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the solution to visualize pores of a membrane.

The first thing you need to do is to check your lattice parameters. I had a membrane of `110*110*70` angstroms, but the pdb file contains the dimensions as `120*120*100`. This is the main issue for me.

**Step 1**

Change the lattice parameters here, `build -> build crystal -> options -> lattice parameters` (check your lattice parameters) and click `apply` and finally `build crystal`

**Step 2**

Go to `Tools -> Atom Volume and Surfaces -> Task-Solvent Surfaces` and change the settings according to your need and `create the isosurface`.

**Step 3**

Right click on the image you have generated go to `display style -> isosurfaces` and increase the `Transparency` slider.

The resulting image will show the pores of your membrane.

Comment: Could you share the final image?

Comment: @camps I thought of doing that. But it isn't yet published. So I'm not sure whether to share or not

Comment: @Camps Here it is: https://pubs.rsc.org/image/article/2021/TA/d1ta04763a/d1ta04763a-f1_hi-res.gif